# MySql - where condition on select if statment result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following example

```
SELECT
     oa.country_id,
     s.country_id,
     (IF(
          s.country_id = oa.country_id,
          DATE_ADD(DATE(so.created_at), INTERVAL 2 DAY),
          DATE_ADD(DATE(so.created_at), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
         )
     ) AS inter
```

And I would like to add where condition as follow:

```
WHERE inter >= CURDATE() -  INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+6 DAY 
    AND inter > CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1 DAY;
```

Is it possible add where to "inter" result?
Or I need to repeat the same if statement query in WHERE twice?

Thnak you.

Comment: What happens when you add `where` to inter like you have shown here?

Comment: You cannot use output column alias in WHERE. Place these conditions to HAVING instead.

Comment: Instead of what you have, edit your original post.  Put in plain statement what you are LOOKING for.  Ex: I am looking to pull dates created based on xxxx.  However, if a country ID is yyyy I need to change the interval (such as delivery from one country to another may expect longer delays.  A delay in delivery should not impact the time period of data you are looking for.  Once revised, you might get a better option to solve your needs, not just how to fix a where condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `inter` in the `WHERE` clause because column aliases are not understood there.  You *could* use a CTE or subquery.

However, MySQL extends the use of `HAVING` for non-aggregation queries.  So you can add a `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING inter >= CURDATE() -  INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+6 DAY AND
       inter > CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1 DAY;
```

Note:  The logic of the expression does not look correct -- but this is the expression in your question.  The first part is more restrictive, so the second part is redundant.  Perhaps you intend `<` for one of them.

Comment: Logic is not correct? I'm try to find rows that been created date plus 2 or 5 more days and the result of that must be in date last 7 days.

Comment: @Klick . . . This answers the question you asked, which is about using `inter` for filtering.  If you have a question about *logic*, then ask a **new** question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.